# Multiple graph command doesn't work in R plot?

Tags: r, plot

In the below code, I am going to show two graphs in a same plot in R but it does not work and it does not return any error. Although the first graph has shown with plot command, the second one doesn't work with lines or points command. What should I do to resolve this problem?

```
urmia = read.csv('urmia_validation.csv',header = TRUE, sep = "," )


plot(strptime(urmia$Time, "%m/%d/%Y"), urmia$NDWI_RNIR,  xlab = 'Time', ylab = 'Water Elevation (m)', 
     main = 'Urmia Water Elevation',  col = 'blue', pch = 16, type = 's', lwd = 2, lty = 1)


lines(strptime(urmia$Time, "%m/%d/%Y"), urmia$MNDWI_GSWIR,  xlab = 'Time', ylab = 'Water Elevation (m)', 
      main = 'Urmia Water Elevation',  col = 'red', pch = 16, type = 's', lwd = 2, lty = 1)
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal sample of your data, then people are more likely to help you!

Comment: the sample data has attached.
https://mega.nz/file/pOhC1bxY#lHTPoo211Y9qCW9yq7MK9VD-RZ8hS81kfTu7keRd2eM